# Clickable effect for a white Button in android

Tags: android

### I have make clickable effect on other color buttons But how to generate clickable effect for a white button

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/featured_listing_button_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botton_account_middle_white"
            android:text="Featured Listing" />
```

**What i have tried** :: I have made the button White, some other properties

**But clickable effect is not present now !**

**botton_account_middle_white.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3px"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />



    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

### How to give clickable effect for the button ! ... White button

Comment: it is unclear what your issue is and what do you want to achieve

Comment: I am trying to get a clickable effect for the button .... specially white one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **selector** for Highlighting a Button.

button_selector.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <item 
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:color="@color/normal" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:color="@color/pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:color="@color/pressed" />
</selector>
```

Use it like

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/featured_listing_button_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Featured Listing" />
```

Comment: For a white button ... which color combinations should i need to use?

Comment: @user2910566 for white use #FFFFFF.

Comment: but android:color="@color/pressed" .& @color/normal ... the color combination there !

Comment: @user2910566 create a color.xml in values folder and define  <color name="normal">#CCCCCC</color>
    <color name="pressed">#FFFFFF</color>

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" /> 
  </selector>
```

```xml
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:background="@drawable/selector" />
```